# What is the usage of an `implicit def` without arguments in Scala?

Tags: scala

I saw this piece of code and I don't know how it will be used. I learned that `implicit def` is used for implicit conversion and it comes with an argument so that it can convert its argument to another type. Please help to explain the usage of the implicit below, any example is great. Thank you in advance!

```scala
  implicit def eitherWrites[A: Writes, B: Writes] = Writes[Either[A, B]]({
    case Left(a) => implicitly[Writes[A]].writes(a)
    case Right(b) => implicitly[Writes[B]].writes(b)
  })
```

Comment: Nobody uses `implicit def` for implicit conversions. Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's comment below is a much more useful interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax `A: Writes` in the type parameter of `eitherWrites` is called a [*context bound*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#context-bounds-and-view-bounds).

```scala
def foo[T: C]
```

is syntactic sugar for

```scala
def foo[T](implicit evidence: C[T])
```

In other words: `eitherWrites` *does* have not one but two (implicit) parameters, since it is syntactic sugar for

```scala
implicit def eitherWrites[A, B](
  implicit evidence`1: Writes[A], 
           evidence`2: Writes[B]
) = Writes[Either[A, B]]({
  case Left(a) => implicitly[Writes[A]].writes(a)
  case Right(b) => implicitly[Writes[B]].writes(b)
})
```

Comment: How will that implicit be used? Will be it used for convert the type of receivers or be passed as implicit parameters?

Comment: @DucLe that kind of definition is what is sometimes called implicit derivation, you can read it like: For any two types `A` & `B`, if you can prove me a `Writes[A]` and a `Writes[B]` then I can give you a `Writes[Either[A, B]]`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: I can't tell whether the "prove me" is a typo for "provide me" or not … and the fact that I can't tell is a beautiful illustration of the Curry-Howard Isomorphism, because both make sense and both mean the same thing!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I meant _"prove"_ as in proof from logic, yes. Since English is not my mother language, I am not sure if I used a valid but not as common word due to being too literal with my translation from Spanish _"prueba"_; this wouldn't have been the first time that happens to me. - About the _"Curry-Howard"_ it is indeed a beautiful coincidence that both word would lead to the same definition :D

Answer (score 3):

I can show you a different example to understand how `implicit def` is used in your case:

```
  // a Haskell-like type class that provides textual representation
  trait Show[T] {
    def show(x: T): String
  }

  object Show {

    def show[T: Show](x: T): String = implicitly[Show[T]].show(x)

    implicit val showString: Show[String] = identity(_)
    implicit val showInt: Show[Int]       = _.toString

    implicit def showTup[T: Show, U: Show]: Show[(T, U)] =
      tup => s"(${Show.show[T](tup._1)}, ${Show.show[U](tup._2)})"
  }
```

The `implicit def` is called a *type class derivation* or *implicit derivation*. Basically it gives you the ability to create a new type class based on current existing implicit parameters and implicit conversions that describes how to compose them together automatically.

The next 3 lines are equivalent:

```
  println(Show.show(123, "abc"))                  // (abc, 123)
  println(Show.show((123, "abc")))                // (abc, 123)
  println(Show.show(123 -> "abc"))                // (abc, 123)
```

Note the parameter here is a tuple of 2 elements, since `show` takes one argument. In this case, the compiler inserts an implicit conversion with 2 implicit parameters. The desugared code is:

```
  println(Show.show(123, "abc")(showTup(showInt, showString)))
```

You can also do:

```
println(Show.show((123, "abc"), (123, "abc")))  // ((123, abc), (123, abc))
```

This is a bit trickier to figure out how the compiler translates it, but the general rule remains: implicit parameters are inserted after the normal parameters, in a separate argument list. The desugared code is:

```
  println(
    Show.show((123, "abc"), (123, "abc"))(
      showTup(showTup(showInt, showString), showTup(showInt, showString))
    )
  )
```

If you can't figure it out on your own, run your code with the `-Xprint:typer` option, and the `scalac` compiler will show you what your code looks like after all implicit conversions have been added by the type checker.

This looks odd at first, but once you figure it out, it's actually quite limited because it only works with tuples of 2 elements. So for example, if you want a tuple of 3 elements, you'd have to write another `implicit def` that takes 3 context bounds and so on. Your example exhibits similar behavior.